# MembershipCreateStatus.InvalidEmail being reached with valid email addresses

Tags: .net, validation, email, membership-provider

Using the .NET Membership Provider and trying to re-create an Add User page which has been used by other developers (the actual developer has left my company). But while most things work, like editing users, I can't add a new user because this wizard is marking all emails as invalid. I don't know how to update the configuration of the provider to stop marking valid emails as invalid. The emails pass the .NET regular expression validation of "Internet Email".

Answer (score 0):

It seems the actual developer set wrong value to [EmailRegularExpression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.createuserwizard.emailregularexpression.aspx) property of CreateUserWizard control.